# dropdown appears behind ajaxmodalpopup

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using ajaxmodalpopupextender in my code. The popup dialog contains three dropdowns and a textbox. However the dropdowns appear behind the popup.

Css for modal popup is as follows:

```
.modalBackground
{
    background-color: Black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.modalPopup
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;    

}
```

I have used select2 jquery for dropdown styling.

Comment: Have you tried by giving a higher z-index value to your modalpopup ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the css `z-index` is higher.

**NOTE**: **`z-index`** only works on ***`positioned elements`***